# Angular Mattable Collapse row on click

Tags: angular, mat-table

I'm having trouble to collapse rows on my angular table. I want it to collapse when I click on another row, but using the same pattern as this one https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-expandable-rows it doesn't work.
I think it's because I'm calling an other function on click (I reload the mattable in the expanded row by calling my database).
I tried :
(click) = "MyFunction"
(click) = "expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element" (pattern)

and (click) = "MyFunction ; expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element"

None of this works, when I add the pattern it doesn't even expand anymore.

Here is a copy of the actual code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j2tuj6?file=src/app/app.component.css (but wont work since it needs backend)

Comment: if possible please reproduce your example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/), so we can test and help you to resolve your problem, the data isn't matter, you can change this example as well https://stackblitz.com/angular/xoorvjaeroq?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts

Comment: I made it on stackblitz, so you can see how it is actually (I edited the post, but here is the link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j2tuj6?file=src/app/app.component.css )

Comment: your example isn't working because of missing dependencies in the stackblitz, I couldn't make it work, but I can recommend you to check at first the logic and second make sure you have added all of the styles and animation from the material example